# Angular-ui-router and href='#'

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular-ui-router and have an issue with empty a tags, like href='#'. I'm using bootstrap, which makes extensive use of href='#' for dropdowns and such. The problem is if a user selects a dropdown item then the router interprets that as a state change, which in this case is to the home page.

Is there an easy way to stop this behavior without having to resort to changing all the href='#' to href=''.

Comment: Can't you just remove the href attribute completely? It works for me when I'm using bootstrap and angular.

Comment: Yeah, is that safe cross-browser? I guess so, but just wanted be sure.

Comment: An interesting side note, the basic angular router doesn't do this.

Comment: Or you can also do this : href="javascript: void(0);"

Comment: Yes, it should be cross browser compatible. You could use anchor tags without href to create an in-page bookmark since HTML was invented. I added my comment as an answer in case you wanted to accept it :)

Comment: Take a look at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ native angular directives and helpers for bootstrap. Replaces the jQuery pluggins provided my bootstrap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the href tag completely from your anchor tag. It's still a perfectly valid tag without it.

Or if you're currently using `ui-sref` in the anchor tag, you could actually use the `href` attribute instead to go to the route that the state is mapped to.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did in the end.

Comment: Why did someone downvote my answer? Care to give an explanation?

Comment: In the Bootstrap collapse, we need to do something like this: <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#3">, how can it work without the href?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen, in that case, I would use the collapse or accordion directives that come with Angular-UI: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Yep removal of href="#" does the thing. But it seems ui-router scroll ui-sref=('#', 'element') only once. The second click did nothing. So to fix this thing i use something like that:

  this.scrollToElement = function (id) {
   $location.hash(id);
   $anchorScroll();
  };

Answer (score 2):

you can use this, so you can preserve the link and basically do nothing when its clicked

```
<a ui-sref="state" href="javascript:void(0);">Your link</a>
```

Comment: I have used your code like below which works <a ui-sref="state" href="#collapseOne">Your link</a>

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
<a href-void>Click me! I don't do anything, but i'm still a link!</a>
```