# UI-Router href="#' not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the bootstrap dropdown menu example to work with UI-Router:

```
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Page 1
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

I tried the solutions from [Angular-ui-router and href='#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552556/angular-ui-router-and-href) with no luck.  It's currently interpreting # as state change and redirecting me back to home since it can't match it.  What is the best practice approach for using href="#" with UI-Router?

Comment: Are you using [UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#top) ?

Comment: @JeanJacques Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yDN1eXTViM4nZxPBFwD9?p=preview) is a working plunker using **UI-Router** and **Boostrap Dropdown**. If you remove the `href` attribute, it doesn't cause any ploblem or redirection

Comment: Thank you sir, that is what I was looking for!